# How to create a virtual ISO file from /dev/sr0

Tags: android, iso, vlc, dvd

I want to create a virtual ISO file from /dev/sr0, without having to create an actual ISO file.  The purpose is to share it to an Android device running VLC.  Android/VLC is only able to open discs (with menu support, etc) as an ISO file.

Comment: For others like me who had trouble understanding what is being done: this is basically opposite of a [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device). The goal is to make a block device appear as if it was a regular file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out the solution was easy using 'mount --bind'.

The 'fake' ISO can be shared and VLC opens it like a DVD, with full menu support.

```
touch dvd.iso
sudo mount --bind /dev/sr0 dvd.iso
```

Comment: You should mark this as an answer to your question. Makes it easier to search for.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I tried to accept it, but StackExchange says I have to wait 2 days.

Comment: If the only problem was with the name, why not just use a symbolic link? This then won't require root access.

Comment: Symbolic link did not work.  VLC opened it like a folder and showed contents rather than loading it as a disc.